# Getting links from different Xpaths selectors

Tags: scrapy

Html code is here  only for one sample >>   `<a id="ctl00_cphContent_ctlRealtyListNew1_rptRealtyList_lnkOverlay_4" title="abc" class="overlay-link" href="/ab/abc/details?sParam=aDrxJwPY%2ed8m4SYfxXoC8w==&amp;new=1"></a>`

and Xpaths samples  >>

```
//*[@id="ctl00_cphContent_ctlRealtyListNew1_rptRealtyList_lnkOverlay_1"]
//*[@id="ctl00_cphContent_ctlRealtyListNew1_rptRealtyList_lnkOverlay_4"]
```

I need to select to multiple links on a page.But I cannot figure out how I can do it ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to ignore the number after `lnkOverlay`, in which case instead of matching the string explicitly you can use the xpath `contains()' function. This expression matches the body of the string and ignores the numbers at the end.

```
'//*[contains(@id,"ctl00_cphContent_ctlRealtyListNew1_rptRealtyList_lnkOverlay")]'
```

Depending on the other IDs in the page you could reduce the quoted string further. See the xpath docs here http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp.

Comment: Definitely great idea.This works for my problem.Thank you for help.